# Combination Vertical And Horizontal Accordion

Tags: jquery, html, accordion

I was wondering if anybody has ever seen a combination vertical and horizontal jQuery accordion (and if there are any demos on the web).

What I mean is that I've created a vertical accordion as a menu on a site that is the left column of the body of the site. When the vertical accordion opens up, I'd like to be able to choose one of the menu items and a larger horizontal accordion opens up to the right to display the relevant content.

I haven't been able to find anything like this and just wanted to see if anybody had heard of this. Thanks.

Comment: there is nothing to be heard of such concepts, you can try to work on it create a demo project and work on what you need as per the requirement and incase there is any difficulty we can solve it.. why are you searching on web. You dont have logical and technical knowledge to create your own.

Comment: He is searching for solutions on the web because that's the smart thing to do. Why would you suggest he reinvent something that has already been built, tested, and distributed for free?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SlideDeck](http://www.slidedeck.com/) comes close. Look at the example accordion's second slide to see their version of a combination accordion.

Comment: That's great, thanks. Not exactly what I'm looking for (I don't know if my idea exists yet), but it's close enough that I can tweak it a bit to fit what I'm doing.